# Proof of continuity using Epsilon-Delta

Tags: continuity

> Let 
>   $$f(x) = \left\{ \begin{array}{lr} x^2 \cos\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) &: x \ne 0 \\ 0 &: x = 0 \end{array}\right.$$
>   Prove that $f(x)$ is continuous for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

I can use a theorem which states: let $I, J \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ be intervals. Let $f:I \to \mathbb{R}$  and $g:J \to \mathbb{R}$  and suppose $f(I) \subseteq J$. Suppose $f$ is continuous at $y \in I$ and $g$ is continuous at $f(y)$. Then $g \circ f$ is continuous at $y$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** For the case $x=0$, note that

> $$|x^2\cos(1/x)-0|\leq |x|^2 < \epsilon. $$

Comment: How so? I'm just not seeing it.

Comment: Nevermind, I think I got it. Thank you.

Comment: @Maddy: you are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

$\textbf{Hint:}$ Use your theorem to prove that $f$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R} - \{0\}$, and prove that $f$ is continuous in $0$ with an $\epsilon-\delta$ argument.

Comment: (In fact, one cannot use the theorem on $x=0$!)